# Laravel Livewire - Edit form overriding data & Select validation

Tags: laravel

I have setup a livewire form, this is running fine but if there is a validation error it reverts the values back to the original, how can i prevent this from happening ?

Lets say i have two inputs firstname and lastname, both of which are required and min length of 4

if i click on the edit form i am presented with the following.

Firstname - Jane
Lastname - Bloggs

I change this to

firstname - John
Lastname - Doe

this will fail validation as lastname is less than 4, but this then revers back to the Jane Bloggs.

So how do i keep the values ?

i have tried to add this to the mount()

```
        if (old('first_name')) {
        $this->first_name = old('first_name');
        }
```

Secondly why does validation not work on select? ive tried to look through the docs and google but struggle to find any relation to select elements. i have no issues with the input elements ?

I have tried to add code to the mount to return the old values but nothing, have been searching google and stack overflow all days for answers.

Just expect the edit form not revert back to original values if validation error and to also be able to validate select elements.

Thanks

Comment: By using `wire:model.lazy`
the form field values will only be updated when you submit the form. This means that if there's a validation error, Livewire won't revert the values to their original state immediately.

Comment: In your Blade view, update your form fields to use
`<form wire:submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <input type="text" wire:model.lazy="first_name">
    <input type="text" wire:model.lazy="last_name">
    <!-- Other form fields -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
`

Comment: thanks @HunterEyes i found the issue as i was getting value in render instead of mount, which has fixed this issues. Just need to get select to validate no matter what i try its not working?